# How to show html in a conditional statement

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to render html outside my conditional statement on a jsp file and cannot get the html to show on the else clause:

```
 <%@ page language="java"  %>

 <%
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
 if (!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()){
// not logged in 
  response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");


 }else{ //display html 
 %>

 <html>
 .....
 </html>

 <% } %>
```

I have tried removing the else clause like this but with no html displaying. Session detection is working.

```
 <%@ page language="java"  %>

 <%
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
 if (!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()){
// not logged in 
  response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");


 } %>

 <html> .... </html>
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is it a lot nicer to do this like

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>index.jsp</title>
</head>

<body>

<c:if test="${sessionScope.LOGGEDINUSER == null}">
<c:redirect url="login.jsp" />
</c:if>

<c:if test="${sessionScope.LOGGEDINUSER != null}">
<c:redirect url="somewhere.jsp" />
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i cannot redirect it somewhere else like that because it has to be that index html or i risk going in a loop

Comment: sounds like you should be using a filter then.

Answer (score 0):

A JSP always creates a session unless one already exists or it has been asked not to create one in the page directive. Furthermore, session is an implicit JSP scripting object. Therefore you don't have to use

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

Also, the method

```
request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()
```

will always return false when the session is new. A session is new when the client hasn't joined the session yet. The client is able to join the session on the second request to your web app by sending the session cookie back to the server. If you refresh your page in the browser, then it should display the HTML you want to show the client.
As Scary Wombat suggested, you should change your design.